# How to display filtered media elements in wordpress media uploader?

Tags: wordpress

I've been running back and forth in the js files in the `wp-includes` folder and already frustrated by the search results but nothing seems to suffice my necessity.

I need to filter the list of media elements displayed in the `Wordpress media uploader`.

I've integrated a `Upload media` button in my theme. You can click on that button and a modal pops up. You can upload your file or select from the list. By default this list happens to contain every elements uploaded so far. But the button I've designed has somewhat more specific operation. Like user can select only pdf files in a place and may be only images in some other. Basically I need to filter the list of media items based on my button preference.

I tracked down (might be wrong though) `MediaFrame` is responsible to display elements, `wp.media.model.Attachments` probably holds the collection of elements which uses `wp.media.model.Query.get()` to query for media elements which sends a `admin-ajax` request with `query-attachments` action along some query params. I searched for the actual ajax function and found a `post_mime_type` query param. I just need to pass my desired mime type there.

So how can I pass my desired mime type when initiating the `wp.media.frame`?

Any type of help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some more digging around and messing with the core `js` and `php` files related to this feature I was finally figure out the actual process and surprisingly thats really simple.

`wp.media()` function accepts some parameters which is obvious-

- **title** Text to show on the uploader
- **button** Select button
- **multiple** whether to select multiple files or not
- **library** This is actually where the filter params are kept

And some more I suppose (couldn't figure out yet). Just passed my mime type there and voila! The list is organised!

```
var file_frame;
file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    library: {
        //  I don't know why but the following two were already 
        // there even when I wasn't passing anything.
        orderby: "date", 
        query: true, 
        post_mime_type: ['image/png'] // pass all mimes in array
    },
});
```

Thats all!!